# Using native EE search to create A to Z search

Tags: search

I need to know how to create an A to Z search using the native ExpressionEngine search, not an add on. Is it possible to do this and display results alphabetically by letter? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

The native EE Search module does *not* have the ability to search either the Title or any custom field based only on the first letter contained therein, no. It also contains no hooks to allow you to manipulate the search query.

Just buy [Low Alphabet](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-alphabet) and be done with it!

Comment: FYI, Low Search 3 also supports simple starts_with options with its Field Search filter: http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/filters#field-search-parameters